# How to pass an ID to read a Json from assets folder

Tags: typescript, assets, angular6

```
id = localStorage.getItem('currentUser')
this.http.get('./assets/id/profiles/admin.json')
                .subscribe(result => {
                  this.profile = result.json();
                });
```

Getting id values from local storage with that id, trying to read json.
How to pass that id to read that particular json.

Comment: Do you mean `'./assets/' + id + '/profiles/admin.json'`? Also what does this have to do with Angular or TypeScript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
this.http.get('./assets/' + id +' /profiles/admin.json')
               .subscribe(result => {
                 this.profile = result.json();
               });
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution for your scenario,

```
    let id = localStorage.getItem('currentUser');

    this.http.get(`assets/${id}/profiles/admin.json`)
        .subscribe(result=> {
            this.profile = result.json();
            //do some stuff 
        })
```

Worked perfect for me.Let try this once and let me know.

Comment: i tried its working perfect ok. why you are downvoting?. Don't behave like this. If i don't know answer iam not response to him.

Comment: `"assets/" + id + "/profiles/admin.json"` or `\`assets/${id}/profiles/admin.json\``.

Comment: Just fix your answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your suggestion.